# Get specific word from a text

Tags: javascript

I have a text like this:

```js
var textVar = "Hello b/3125 this is a text.";
```

I want to get b/3125 from this text. But b/3125 will not be exact all the time. It could be b/29152 or b/testvarxe etc. (it will always start with b/ though).

There is not a specific length too so slice is not what i am looking for.

So I want to get [random-length-text] from a text which has b/[random-length-text].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match `b/`, followed by digits (`\d+`):

```js
var textVar = "Hello b/3125 this is a text.";
const match = textVar.match(/b\/\d+/);
console.log(match[0]);
```

To be more general, you could match non-space characters with `\S` instead of `\d`:

```js
var textVar = "Hello b/3125wefwe this is a text.";
const match = textVar.match(/b\/\S+/);
console.log(match[0]);
```

Or only alphanumeric with `[\da-z]`, looking ahead for a space:

```js
var textVar = "Hello b/3125BAD$fwe b/3125GOOD this is a text.";
const match = textVar.match(/b\/[\da-z]+(?= )/i);
console.log(match[0]);
```

Comment: I also want to make it work with letters what should I change?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is always the second word and there is no extra spaces you can use this method:

```
var textVar = "Hello b/3125 this is a text.";
var code    = textVar.split(" ")[1];
```